# PGF output from matplotlib not adjusted to the LaTeX template

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, latex, pgf

My goal is to use the font and its size from the template (in my particular case the [`ieeetran.cls`](http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)) for my plots.

With Python/Jupyter and `matplotlib` I create a plot which I store as pgf file, which works fine:

```
plt.rcParams.update({
    'font.family': 'sans-serif', # used for the plot in Jupyter
    'text.usetex': True, # used for the plot in Jupyter
    'pgf.rcfonts': False, # actually I thought this is the essential line
})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.16, 3), dpi=300)
# do the plot
plt.savefig('../reports/plot.pgf')
```

But in the latex file, using

```
\input{figures/plot.pgf}
```

the fonts in the plot (especially the size) is not set correctly:

[image]

Please notice the different sizes for the caption and the legend or numbers.

I thought setting up `'pgf.rcfonts': False` does the trick... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the same figure with a different `cls` and see if the fonts are okay? Or perhaps with a simple [example](https://www.sbillaudelle.de/2015/02/23/seamlessly-embedding-matplotlib-output-into-latex.html)? I wonder if the font properties are from the document class itself.

Comment: Yes, I did, the same problem occurred. I also linked the cls file (IEEEtran.cls).